# Assign values to array in for loop VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can any one kindly check the code, I explained the code in comments.

I am getting run error 13

My concern in the assign method that I am using. I want to assign the cell value in the array starting form position 0

Thank you very mush

```
Sub zones()

Dim Top10zones(0 To 9) As Long
Dim found As Boolean

Top10zones(0) = 309101502

NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

Dim Arry As Variant

Dim count As Integer
count = 0

' find the 10zones in row 1.
Range("A1").Select
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         If ActiveCell.Value = Top10zones(0) Then
            found = True
            Exit Do
         End If

         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
      Loop
   ' if found move to row 2 in the same cloumn.
      If found = True Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

      For j = 2 To NumRows
      If ActiveCell.Value <= 1 Then
         ' if the value <= 1 assign cells(j,1) to the array.
        Arry(count) = Cells(j, 1).Value
        count = count + 1
      End If
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

      ' repeat the process.
      Next j


      End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: To save time please tell us which line errors.

Comment: `Arry` isn't magically an array, so `Arry(count) = Cells(j, 1).Value` is problematic.

Comment: Also don't use a loop to find something, use `Range.Find`.

Comment: a) Use a worksheet qualifier when using `Cells` method. b) I don't see you dimension your array anywhere?

Comment: @BigBen  `Arry(count) = Cells(j, 1).Value` what is the way to fix it. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, arrays are initialized with a fixed length. For instance, an array of length 1 will only have a `Array(0)` index and none others. If you want to increase the size of the array (without destroying the current contents of the array), you need to use `ReDim Preserve Arry(new_length)`. So if you `ReDim Preserve Arry(10)` your array is now ready for 10 elements, and if you had any elements already in the array they are preserved.

There are two ways to initialize an array.

1)

```vb
Dim myArry(0 to 1) as String
```

This is an array with two empty elements ready to accept a string.

2)

```vb
Dim myArry as Variant
myArry = Array("", "")
```

This is an array with two "empty" element ready to accept a string.

To change the length:

```vb
For i = 1 to 10
    ReDim Preserve myArry(i)
    myArry(i) = 'whatever
Next i
```

Comment: @sjr good point about 1, it was early in the morning for me. To your second point, I just wanted to illustrate that it's an empty Variant that then becomes an array.